# SQL Server function with parameters

Tags: sql-server

I am creating a SQL Server function

```
ALTER function [dbo].[GetAbnormalProductionHourFlag]
    (@startDate date, 
     @endDate date, 
     @employeeId integer, 
     @lowBand decimal, 
     @highBand decimal) 
returns integer
as
begin
    declare @flagCount integer

    set @flagCount = (select count(*) 
                      from AHFAB_vTimecardLines
                      where lmlActualStartTime >= @startDate
                        and (lmlActualEndTime < @endDate or lmlActualEndTime is null)
                        and lmlEmployeeID = @employeeId
                        and (jmoActualProductionHours < @lowBand or jmoActualProductionHours > @highBand))

    return @flagCount
```

and call the function

```
select dbo.GetAbnormalProductionHourFlag1('2017/02/01', '2017/02/17', 5124, 0.10, 3.00)
```

When I try to debug, for some reason the value of `@lowBand` on the watchlist SQL debugger is passed as `0`, instead of `0.1`

Is there a special way to pass decimal value parameters to a SQL Server function?

I am confused, I thought by putting decimal on parameters type, it should pass the correct value.

I would appreciate it if you could shed some light on what I miss or what I do wrong.

Comment: decimal defaults to 0 scale, so yes. try `decimal(9,3)`

Answer (score 1):

The default for `decimal` is `decimal(18,0)`, meaning 0 decimal digits. You have to give precision and scale explicitly like `decimal(18,9)`.

This is described [here on msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms187746.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Better yet, rewrite it as an **inline table-valued function**:

```
create function [dbo].[GetAbnormalProductionHourFlag_inline] (
    @startDate date
  , @endDate date
  , @employeeId integer
  , @lowBand decimal(19,6)
  , @highBand decimal(19,6)
) 
returns table as return (
  select FlagCount = count(*) 
  from AHFAB_vTimecardLines
  where lmlActualStartTime >= @startDate
    and (lmlActualEndTime < @endDate 
        or lmlActualEndTime is null)
    and lmlEmployeeID = @employeeId
    and (jmoActualProductionHours < @lowBand 
        or jmoActualProductionHours > @highBand)
);
go

select FlagCount 
from dbo.GetAbnormalProductionHourFlag_inline('2017/02/01', '2017/02/17', 5124, 0.10, 3.00)
```

reference:

- [When is a SQL function not a function? "If it’s not inline, it’s rubbish." - Rob Farley](http://blogs.lobsterpot.com.au/2011/11/08/when-is-a-sql-function-not-a-function/)
- [Inline Scalar Functions - Itzik Ben-Gan](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/inline-scalar-functions)
- [Scalar functions, inlining, and performance: An entertaining title for a boring post - Adam Machanic](http://dataeducation.com/scalar-functions-inlining-and-performance-an-entertaining-title-for-a-boring-post/)
- [TSQL User-Defined Functions: Ten Questions You Were Too Shy To Ask - Robert Sheldon](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/sql-training/tsql-user-defined-functions-ten-questions-you-were-too-shy-to-ask/)

Answer (score 0):

Redefine @lowBand as float.

```
ALTER function [dbo].[GetAbnormalProductionHourFlag]
(@startDate date, 
 @endDate date, 
 @employeeId integer, 
 @lowBand float, 
 @highBand float) 
 returns integer
 as
begin
declare @flagCount integer

set @flagCount = (select count(*) 
                  from AHFAB_vTimecardLines
                  where lmlActualStartTime >= @startDate
                    and (lmlActualEndTime < @endDate or lmlActualEndTime is null)
                    and lmlEmployeeID = @employeeId
                    and (jmoActualProductionHours < @lowBand or jmoActualProductionHours > @highBand))

return @flagCount
```

Comment: `float` is inherently imprecise and tends to produce rounding errors etc. - I would recommend **not** to use `float` but `decimal` instead ....